# Pass JavaBean to Struts 1 tiles

Tags: java, web-applications, jstl, javabeans, struts-1

I just started developing a web application using struts 1.3.10 tiles framework. There is something I am not so clear.

Suppose I have a tiles definition in tiles-def.xml:

```
<definition name="body" path="/layouts/BodyLayout.jsp">
    <put name="displayUnit" value="/tiles/displayUnit.jsp"/>
</definition>
```

The "displayUnit.jsp" is a modularized jsp page that contains some basic tiles module:

```
<div>
    <!-- Some html here-->
</div>
```

This basic structure is operating on a single JavaBean:

```
public class DisplayUnitBean() {
private String color;
private String bgcolor;

public String getBgColor() {
    return bgcolor;
}

public String getColor() {
    return color;
}

public void setBgColor(String bgcolor) {
    this.bgcolor = bgcolor;
}

public void setColor(String color) {
    this.color = color;
}
}
```

In the layout jsp "BodyLayout.jsp", I would like to insert a few basic tiles modules "displayUnit.jsp":

```
<tiles:insert attribute="displayUnit"/>
<tiles:insert attribute="displayUnit"/>
<tiles:insert attribute="displayUnit"/>
<tiles:insert attribute="displayUnit"/>
```

And each of these tiles modules is using a different "DisplayUnitBean" instance to be displayed in different ways.

Obviously, I need some dynamic codes (JSTL based maybe) inside "displayUnit.jsp" to retrieve JavaBean parameters. And, I also need to pass different JavaBeans to different "displayUnit.jsp" pages while inserting them.

I wonder how I can accomplish this, and whether it's possible to do it at all. If not, I wish to know the correct paradigm to code this web application.

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

refer this [struts1 tiles example](http://www.vaannila.com/struts/struts-example/struts-tiles-example-1.html)

Codes for mappings, definitions, etc are explained there with screen shots and codes..